# D / DLang / GDC - Alignment of SIMD fields in struct

Tags: gcc, struct, d, simd, memory-alignment

```
struct vec_struct {
    alias field this;
    bool b;
    int8 field; // ymm 
    }
```

In this code when you look at the generated x64 code output by GDC it seems to be doing a nice job, because it has got the offset right for the 256-bit YMM 'field' correct.

**Q**: Does D automatically propagate the alignment restrictions on the field to the allocation of static structs or structs on the stack?

In this case -

```
struct vec_struct {
    bool b2;
    struct {
        alias field this;
        bool b;
        int8 field; // umm
        }
    }
```

it appears that the offset to 'field' is no longer aligned correctly - offset is 40 bytes in GDC. I don't suppose the compiler will use solely unaligned instructions? In any event, I could take the address of field and then pass that to someone expecting to pick up something with guaranteed correct alignment, if I have understood the D docs. **Q**: Is this correct - a seriously bad problem, or am I being daft?

Please don't bite. I'm both new to D and I hope I have understood the x86 SIMD instructions' docs. (Very experienced professional asm and C programmer, but v out-of-date.)

Noob q: I notice that the GDC opcodes look a bit odd, for example the compiler generates a 256-bit unaligned fetch followed by an aligned binary operation (I think), eg a movdqu followed by a vpaddd r, ymm ptr blah - is the latter aligned-only? Apologies if I have got this wrong, need to read up. *Would someone be kind enough to sanity-check me?*

Comment: Most operations like vpaddd (I didn't check that one in particular) accept an unaligned memory operand, it is mostly mov that has a strictly aligned variant.

Comment: Thanks Marc, my ignorance - I had assumed too much, so unless I take another look at it, there is no evidence that this is crashing code as (some of) the moves that I have seen are explicitly unaligned. It might be considered very much suboptimal though in the case of having sub-structs on the wrong alignment, after all, it tries to get alignment correct usually.

Comment: It may be also that there is a problem with the requirements imposed by the spec. If compatibility with some C / C++ compiler (which?) or someone's ABI spec is mandated, then there could be trouble if the alignment problem gets fixed, but then that would of course mean that the other ‘governing’ spec is broken in the first place, so perhaps who cares, and maybe this is not a valid point.

Comment: I wonder if this a general problem with alignment restrictions of fields not propagating outwards, fields -> (sub-)structs -> containing structs -> restrictions on allocation of objects. There has to be a mechanism in existence already for ensuring this is done properly, surely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does D automatically propagate the alignment restrictions on the field to the allocation of static structs or structs on the stack?

I think it's supposed to and GDC/LDC should already support proper stack alignment. DMD probably has some bugs in this regard:
https://issues.dlang.org/show_bug.cgi?id=16098

> it appears that the offset to 'field' is no longer aligned correctly - offset is 40 bytes in GDC.

As Iain already answered in the D.learn thread this is a bug in the shared DMD/GDC codebase.

Bug report: https://issues.dlang.org/show_bug.cgi?id=17237

DMD bugfix: https://github.com/dlang/dmd/pull/6582

Backport for GDC: https://github.com/D-Programming-GDC/GDC/pull/408